# External msproject, imported in CMake, would not build

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I have a CMake-based C++ project, and recently I've included existing C# program into it.

Here is CMake code:

```
include_external_msproject(MarkTrainingSet MarkTrainingSet.csproj
                        GUID 77A5B8C9-998E-4D0E-A444-6AD14FB0DC37
                        PLATFORM AnyCPU)
```

The .csproj file was generated by the same Visual Studio 2013, as builds my C++ project. GUID value and `AnyCPU` platform are the values from that file.

My problem is that this C# project is not built when I issue `Build solution` command to the Visual Studio. 
I have to go to the solution properties (right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer), then Configuration Properties -> Configuration, and manually check `Build` checkbox in the line, corresponding to my MarkTrainingSet project.

If CMake regenerates the solution, I have to recall about that checkbox and redo the procedure.

The documentation about `include_external_msproject` is very incomplete.

What should I do to make this C# project always build automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I looked, CMake's implememtation of include_external_msproject() is restricted to C/C++ projects.

You may find this defect report worth a look, though it looks stale. http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9742 ... ( also see http://marc.info/?l=cmake&m=133319401303885 )

I couldn't get a sense of whether the patches were included in CMake or not though, but the defect is still open.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the patches were not included. Resolution is still "Open", and search through Kitware's CMake repository doesn't bring added code snippets from patches.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, you could apply the patch to your working version and see if that helps you! If you're feeling really adventurous, you could try to get the patch applied. I think the only thing missing is a warm body to do the work and usher it in.

Answer (score 1):

Generally syntax looks like this:

`include_external_msproject(projectname folder/projectname.csproj PLATFORM AnyCPU)`

Seems to work with vs2019 included cmake.